# Find out how much current a mains adapter can supply?

Tags: power-supply, current, current-measurement, mains, step-down

I have a mains adapter without an enclosure which delivers 12V. Is there a way to find out how much ampere I can draw from it max/safely?

Comment: Read the datasheet, or the markings on the device itself.

Comment: None available. Also I found the answer, I have to analyze the schematics. I'll just throw it away...

Comment: How much current do you need to draw from it? If you added a clear photo (someone will edit it in to your question so it shows up properly) then we might be able to give a fair estimate.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - A "fair estimate" could be really problematic. There is a huge range of energy conversion density possible in adapter designs. Then there is also the consideration, for labeled items, that the numbers may be severely overrated depending upon the country of origin of the adapter.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I was thinking that if the OP needs, say, 200 mA, then if the photo of the unit under suspicion does not look dangerous we could say it will suffice. Perhaps I was being too optimistic. Anyway, OP has said they will throw it away - maybe there are no salvageable components.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "I'll just throw it away..."

Comment: What I meant to say was it will probably safer to just not use it since I need a lot of amps. Of course I'll salvage it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could gradually load up the output with say 100 ohm 2 watt resistors or anything else that you have on hand .Measure the volts and the Amps .At overload point the supply will  start to drop voltage and /or trip out .It may hiccup trying to restart .Set up the load at say 80% of this point and leave the unit running for thermal evaluation .Back the load off further if things are too hot .